# No app found to open .apk file

Tags: installation, apk, side-loading

I turned on unknown source installations, downloaded [Confluence 1.71.13 apk](https://apkgit.com/download/com.atlassian.android.confluence.core_1.71.13_free) via browser. When the download finished I tapped on the notification to sideload it. A message popped up saying:

> No app found to open .apk file

Why did that happen? I can install it via [App Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager), but I don't understand why this happens. [Googling the error](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=no+app+found+to+open+apk) doesn't yield any useful info.

My Android version is 5.1.1.

Comment: How did you sideload it? Is it from a file manager app?

Comment: I downloaded it via browser, then tapped on the notification when the download finished

Answer (score 1):

*-->  If you tap the file from the Download list in your preferred browser, you'll get the error!*

You have to go to the FILE MANAGER, then **there** into your **DOWNLOAD HISTORY** *respectively* **the FOLDER where you saved the .apk file.**

Then *tap the* **.apk file** to open it, then you might have to choose (depending on your basic settings for ***"Installation from Unknown Sources"***) to allow (option for ***"only this time"*** or similar) an installation from an ***"Unknown Source"***.

There you go! :)

Comment: This is the correct answer!